# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: php, simplexml

Trying to parse an XML document to pull out data, getting the following warning

"Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Start tag expected, '<' not found".

I am wondering if strip_tags is to blame or the way the ItemField tags are closed.

PHP looks like this,

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents('catalogmini.xml');
// replace '&' followed by a bunch of letters, numbers
// and underscores and an equal sign with &amp;
$xml2 = strip_tags($xml);
$xml3 = simplexml_load_string($xml2);
?>
```

XML file looks like this basically,

```
<!DOCTYPE Catalog SYSTEM "http://store.yahoo.com/doc/dtd/Catalog.dtd">
  <Catalog StoreID="yhst-11338625352771" StoreName="TeamTailgateShop.com"   PublishTimestamp="1471553199">
  <Item ID="422329cb" TableID="newitem">
  <ItemField TableFieldID="upc" Value="013051464974" />
  </Item>
  </Catalog>
```

Comment: Well, certainly `strip_tags()` is an issue here. I suggest you simply take a look at what you receive back in `$xml2`...

Comment: why are you stripping the tags, then attempting to create a new object from such? N.B. If you must strip tags then you can specify what tags are kept. As suggested, see what `$xml2` contains and if its valid xml

Comment: Apparently its blank so that is the solution to the problem. I need to remove <H2>, and also & and <>. I was able to use $xml = preg_replace('#&(?=[a-z_0-9]+=)#', '&amp;', $xml); to remove the & but cannot figure out how to make that work to remove the other content. That is why I tried the strip_tags.